# SQL - Select records between Start Century/Year/Week & End Century/Year/Week

Tags: sql

I have a file which contains the columns CENT, YEAR & WEEK (all Integer fields)

YEAR is a 2 digit year. CENT is a century indicator, which is either 0 for years < 2000 or 1 for years >= 2000. WEEK is a 2 digit week i.e. 1 - 52

I'm trying to select records between the following:

- From Cent: 1
- From Year: 13
- From Week: 45
- To Cent: 1
- To Year: 14
- To Week: 12

So from Week 45 of 2013, to Week 12 of 2014 inclusive.

For the sake of example assume the file contains 1 record for each week from Year 13 Week 1 to Year 14 Week 52 so:

- CENT = 1, YEAR = 13, WEEK = 1
- CENT = 1, YEAR = 13, WEEK = 2
- CENT = 1, YEAR = 13, WEEK = 3
- ...
- ...
- ...
- CENT = 1, YEAR = 13, WEEK = 52
- CENT = 1, YEAR = 14, WEEK = 1
- ...
- ...
- ...
- CENT = 1, YEAR = 14, WEEK = 52

However, there could also be records for 1999 on this file which would read as:

- CENT = 0, YEAR = 99, WEEK = 1
- CENT = 0, YEAR = 99, WEEK = 2
- CENT = 0, YEAR = 99, WEEK = 3
- ...
- ...
- ...
- CENT = 0, YEAR = 99, WEEK = 52

I do have an idea how to achieve this but the SQL is very long (and possibly not efficient), does anyone know of a shorthand way?

The reason we have century indicators is legacy iSeries files :)

I just need a

```
SELECT * FROM FILENAME WHERE (*** CENT, YEAR & WEEK are between the two sets of Cent/Year/Week ***)
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you give a more ellaborative info? Schema ?

Comment: I was wondering what other info I can give - I'm just doing a Select * where CENT, YEAR, WEEK are between the From & To cent/year/weeks

Answer (score 2):

You can use such construction (similar for lower bound). It is seems ugly but it is keep things sargable.

```
CENT > @centFrom
OR CENT = @centFrom AND YEAR > @yearFrom 
OR CENT = @centFrom AND YEAR = @YearFrom AND WEEK >= @weekFrom
```

Comment: "CENT >= @centFrom" makes any year/week match for CENT=@centFrom

Comment: first condition should be '>', not '>='.
otherwise even if year<@yearFrom, it will match this condition

Comment: That would pick out all records where CENT = 1, which in my  case it all records on the file. The from CENT could be a 0 (pre 2000). Also, the first OR clause would pick out all records for Year 13.

Comment: Getting there, it now picks out the Year 13 records correctly but also selects everything after 13 :)

Comment: Your first OR clause: OR CENT = centFrom AND YEAR > yearFrom would pick out everything after Year 13, where I only need up to Week 12 in Year 14, so i'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Can you provide data for CENT, YEAR and WEEK and values for centFrom, yearFrom and weekFrom to show problem.

Comment: Ok, I've amended the original post to provide some sample data - The values for centFrom, yearFrom and weekFrom (as well as centTo, weekTo & yearTo) are at the top of the post :)

Comment: Still too broad and unclear. Just 6 numbers, which must but not filtered or vise versa by the predicate.

Comment: Ok, i've edited the post again, providing more info about what the CENT, YEAR & WEEK mean. Hope that explains it a bit better :)

Comment: Are CENT, YEAR & WEEK char?

Comment: They are integer fields, although they are specified as decimal on the iSeries CENT is 1,0 - YEAR is 2,0 - WEEK is 2,0